# Using Spring @Transactional to avoid dirty reads in multiple JVMs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I have a spring boot app. I am running multiple instances of this app on different servers. There is a situation where in these different JVM instances read the same table in oracle DB. I have seen that there are dirty reads between these instances of JVM.

To solve this problem can we use @Transactional with isolation level attribute? I believe since the isolation level would lock the rows in DB so it should work across multiple JVMs as well to avoid dirty reads. For instance,

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
```

There is no need of global transactions or something else, I just want to avoid dirty reads.

Comment: If you really only care about preventing dirty reads, then `READ_COMMITTED` would be sufficient and usually less resource intensive.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes Isolation level I can decide but my concern is will this work across multiple JVMs

Comment: Since this setting mostly applies to the DB (and that is already outside of your JVM): yes.